# Need help to rewrite URL

Tags: regex, url, url-rewriting

I am writing some URL rewrite rules like as below:

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite to html" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\/$" ignoreCase="true" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="Images/{R:1}/{R:2}/{R:3}/{R:3}.html" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Rewrite to html image" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)(!\.gif|!\.png|!\.jpg|!\.jpeg)\/?$" ignoreCase="true" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="Images/{R:1}/{R:2}/{R:3}/{R:3}.html" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Rewrite to image" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)(\.gif|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg)$" ignoreCase="true" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="Images/{R:1}/{R:2}/{R:3}/{R:3}{R:4}" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

My URL might be as below:

1. Name/statement/ID
2. Name/statement/ID/
3. Name/statement/ID.jpg

I have written 3 rules for above 3 URLs. I need 3 perfect regex to map these 3 URL for rewriting.

- URL 1 & 2 are same (maps to same location) except a forward slash.
- URL 1 must not contain anything after ID. If user appends any string after id, regex should not validate and return false for this wrong URL.
- URL 2 might have forward slash after ID but it should not contain anything after last forward slash. For example: user types a wrong URL: `Name/statement/ID/ABC`, then it should not match any rewriting rule. But if user types `Name/statement/ID/` in the browser URL then it should match the rule.
- URL 1 & 3 are almost identical in display except a file extension(`.jpg`). So URL must 1 might have any valid image extension or html extension after id, then it should match the rule 3.

Comment: What do you need to rewrite them to? Something like: `index.php?name=$1&statement=$2` etc?

Comment: No. It is something like http://domain/images/Name/statement/ID/ID.jpg or may be an html page http://domain/images/Name/statement/ID/ID.htm.